# How do I get environment variables in Rails from inside a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm making a Ruby on Rails gem and need access to variables like cookie or the query parameters. How do I get this from inside a gem?

```
module MyModule
  def self.my_method
    # need access to cookies, query params, etc
  end
end
```

So that from a controller or view, I can call

```
MyModule.my_method
```

and it'll have the access it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in what you want. Whether you want to pass in each individually or pass in the request object and pull out what you want depends on how/where you'll use your gem.  I would lean towards passing in each individually in a well defined format so there aren't any surprises b/n rails servers and what the request object looks like.